# PHP PDO extension not available is command line

Tags: php, mysql, apache, pdo, easyphp

I've moved from WAMP to EasyPHP and now there are problems using PDO.
PDO works fine when I view the site in the browser, but doesn't work in cmd or when I run the test file via Netbeans.
I get:

> "PDOException: could not find driver"

In `phpinfo()` for Configure Command I have

```
cscript /nologo configure.js " --enable-snapshot-build" " --disable-isapi" " --enable-debug-pack" " --disable-isapi" " --without-mssql" " --without-pdo-mssql" " --without-pi3web" " --with-pdo-oci=D:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk, shared" " --with-oci8=D:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk, shared" " --with-oci8-11g=D:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient11\sdk, shared" " --enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" " --enable-com-dotnet" " --with-mcrypt=static" " --disable-static-analyze"
```

In `php.ini` I have already uncommented these lines:

```
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll

extension=php_mysql.dll
```

Any ideas on how I can get this working?

Comment: It sounds like it is loading the wrong php.ini. `phpinfo()` should tell you that.

Answer (score 6):

When running php from the command line, you can use the `-c` or `--php-ini` argument to point to the `php.ini` file to use.  This will allow you to use one php.ini file for both.  You can also alias `php` to `php -c/path/to/php.ini` if you are running the script yourself.

Answer (score 2):

All web server install should you be in linux or windows usually use 2 different php.ini. One for the CLI (Command line client) and one for APACHE or wathever the server is in easyphp.

I can't help you more than that since i'm on linux and don't use EasyPHP, but look in that direction, maybe a system wide search can help you out?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the problem. As Mathieu Dumoulin pointed out, PHP has loads a different .ini for CLI. So what I did was create a php-cli.ini file under php folder and the problem was solved.